# Template engine for rendering Text Files c#

Tags: c#, templates

I am in the process of writing a class library that will generate an edi file. I am wanting to write a template for the file so that i can pass in some form of a model and generate the file (similar to how ASP MVC functions).

I have looked at t4 files as well as xslt and i have concerns on both. t4 looks to have an interesting way of approaching related classes, and file locks during compile. xslt is possible, but i was hoping there might be something out there that was a bit more intuitive.

I have tried searching to see if this is a duplicate issue, but if it is, please let me know, and my appologies.

Much appreciated.

Comment: If you are already familiar with how ASP.NET MVC works, just use the razor engine. It exists independent of the MVC framework.

Comment: You can't find duplicate because "search for tools/library" is off-topic on SO and hence no duplicates. If you have more concrete requirement (compared to "more intuitive") http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour will likely be correct place to ask.

Comment: Alexei, please forgive my ignorance. Im very much new here, but I read this all the time and see people providing feedback on possible tools to use. Ill check out that link.

Comment: qntmfred. Great tool. I wish I could mark that as the solution.